# Highcharts - Add a pie chart to a line chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to make a combination Line and Pie chart but I'm using 2 Javascript arrays for data inputs as opposed to hard coded values. The syntax I'm using isn't going through. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo

The code below is what's currently implemented and I added the `pieData`. How do I add this to the series so that it shows up as a pie chart in the corner?

Basically instead of hard coding the series, how do you define 2 series for two graphs using two arrays like the ones below?

Kinda-sorta [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w9hqdspd/)

```
 $.each(fuelObj, function (k, i) {
    var genData = [];
    genData.type = 'line';
    genData.name = i.name;
    genData.data = i.flow.sort();
    genData.visible = i.visible;
    genData.color = i.color;
    genData.dashStyle = 'Line';
    genData.events = {
       click: function (event) {
        this.hide();
       }
    };
    seriesData.push(genData);

    var pie = [];
    pie.name = i.name;
    pie.y = i.flow[i.flow.length - 1][1];
    pie.color = i.color;
    pieData.push(pie);
    });
series: genData
```

EDIT:
I'm already using Objects.  `fuelObj` is built like this above the listed code:

```
fuelObj['gas'] = {name: 'gasoline', yest: [], today: [], color: '#00B050', visible: true};
```

Comment: Could you post live example showing your issue? Like jsFiddle?

Answer (score 2):

series typically takes an array of objects.

For example:

```
series: [
  {
   type:'column'
   name:'series 1'
   data:[1,2,3,4,5]  
  },
  {
   type:'spline'
   name:'series 2',
   data[5,6,7,8,9]
  }
]
```

Make sure genData and pieData are objects and then add them to the series array.

Comment: they are objects, that's how I'm building them in the above example

Comment: Your code in the above example is "series: genData,pieData".  I don't see those surrounded by brackets.

Comment: Also, genData and pieData should be equal to { } not equal to [ ].

Comment: As mentioned above I would suggest adding to a jsFiddle so that someone can update and correct any issues. genData is still set to an array "[ ]", not an object "{ }", and the genData object still isn't being passed to a series array.